# Combining and mixing mantras

Tags: mantras

I would like to combine my two mantras into one.  Can Hindu mantras be combined to create on mantra, such as adding and removing words of a certain mantra?

> *Om Gam Kleem Shreem Brezee Aim Ganapataye Namaha*

I want money, friends, a lover soulmate and all resistance & obstacles removed so I can get there.

My intentions are to wrap it all up as one and have it be just as effective and chanting them separate.

Comment: :-) No. That is not how mantras work. BTW, Brezee is not a beejakshara (primordial sound) that I ever heard. Sanskrit does not have a "zee". So brezee is not a known mantra. Pick one mantra. Believe that the deity embodied by that mantra is omnipotent and can give you all that you desire. And you shall receive. Yad bhaavam tat bhavati.

Comment: There is no fast food with mantras. The mantras that you want to chant are in the Atharva Veda, but should be intoned by a brahmin trained in the Atharva Veda. Besides giving you those things you desire, they will also give you endless births (and deaths).

Comment: Taittiriya Samhita (II. iv. 12.) gives a story of what happens when a mantra is not intoned correctly.

Comment: I'm leaving this post up because of the well thought out answer but generally this is NOT an advice site.

Answer (score 1):

## Combining Mantras can have harmful effects

Some people say that the [seed Mantras](http://sciencebehindmantras.blogspot.com/2013/01/beej-mantras.html) like Aum, Haym, Kleem, etc can be combined. However this is NOT RECOMMENDED without guidance from a Guru.

Combining and mixing mantras is very very dangerous. Imagine combining a random set of chemicals in order to combine their advantages. What happens ultimately? Nobody knows!

Similar it is with combining and mixing mantras. Mantras are very useful if chanted rightly, but they can be very dangerous if not! That is why it is safe to chant mantras which one knows and also better yet chant the mantra under guidance of one's Guru.

The [Kshama Prarthana](http://www.stutimandal.com/gif_devi/kshamaa_praarthanaa.htm) is chanted by some devotees after recitation just to expiate the possible harmful effects of wrongly chanting mantras. Imagine then combining them?

## God will Himself take care of the one who has surrendered to Him

However there is an easier way to achieve the same effect that you need. You want money, friends, a lover and all resistance and obstacles removed. The best solution for that is to surrender all of these and control over your life to God (you can call him by any name you want - Sri Krishna, Rama, Lord Shiva, Lord Vishnu, etc [Gita 10:20]).

**Gita 9:22**

> But those who worship Me with devotion, meditating on My transcendental form--to them I carry what they lack and preserve what they have.

Comment: Thank you.  I would love to have a guru.  How can I find one who will work with me?

Comment: That's a really good question! But unfortunately I have no idea how. Because usually the Guru finds you, not other way round! I do know one thing for sure. Pray to God everyday with intense faith that 'Oh Sweet God, I am unable to wait longer, please send me My Guru so that I shall come back to Thee'. Eventually (depending on yearning) God shall send forth His manifestation as Thy Guru and help Thee :)!! all the best. Important thing is to seek God, the rest shall occur automatically